# My phone cannot be detected in eclipse to test run

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

Before asking my question, I have looked through a few threads that share the same problem as me and have tried all the given solution with no success. I am from Malaysia.
I cannot get my device to be detected to test my app on my phone. I have checked both the "Unknown sources" and "USB debugging" settings in my phone. I am using eclipse. But if I create a random virtual device, my app is able to run there.

Okay so I am using a Motorola Atrix 2. And I'm using Windows 8 Pro 64 bit

I have downloaded android SDK bundle from here : http://www.motorola.com/sites/motodev/us-en/motodev_lp.html

I have also tried downloading the latest driver with no success. I have also added this line in the manifest android:debuggable="true"
I have tried both as a mass storage device and a media transferring device.
I would appreciate any help a lot because as of now, I cannot progress further into developing an android app and that saddens me. :(
I have attached a picture of which my android phone should be detected in the window, but as you can see, none.
https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BJu1XSgCYAEGCUd.jpg:large

Comment: I guess you tried to restart eclipse already? (with device connected to PC)

Comment: I had a similar problem with an htc phone and i resolved it by adding some htc brand id to a file on the sdk or something like that maybe you should look into that

Comment: yea, I came across things like that too while hunting for a solution, but I failed to find a proper guide to do that unfortunately..

Answer (score 0):

go to /your-android-sdk-directory/platform-tools using command prompt.

type

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
adb devices
```

n see whether ur device is detected now or not...

Note: if you're using a Linux machine then put **./** before adb

Comment: How do you do that? I am using Win 8 Pro 64 bit.
I mean you start command prompt(admin) and just type that? I did that and it says cannot find specified directory

Comment: when u've opened the command prompt navigate to the directory where you've installed/extracted the android-sdk.. then type cd platform-tools and then type the above 3 lines

Comment: erm, where do you find the platform-tools directory? typing "cd platform-tools" alone seem to result in "The system cannot find the specified path"

Comment: I have installed android-sdk in C:/Program Files/Android/android-sdk folder. so I will go to this folder by typing `cd "C:/Program Files/Android/android-sdk/platform-tools/"`. Now replace the text within "" with the path where you've installed android-sdk and do the rest

Comment: Okay so I did that, but it results in this : https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BJvTgMxCAAApZt8.jpg:large
What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Install proper drivers for your `adb` devices, from `Android-SDK` archive or `Motorola site`.

If you are on `Windows` machine, go to the `device manager` find your device, and select folder with drivers for it.

Comment: Maybe to add, Install everything with admin rights (right-click, run as admin)

Comment: What are the differences between drivers for adb and drivers for phone? There was only 1 driver that was given to me and I updated that via device manager, oh and I'm using Win 8 Pro 64 bit

Comment: Run your `SDK manager` and download `Google USB driver` from `Extras`

Answer (score 0):

Open you windows os's explorer, have a look at the process, if there two or more process hold your adb, try to exits the process

Answer (score 0):

Check that the android:minSdkVersion is lower or equal to the Version running on the phone. If it is higher it wont show on "Android Device Chooser"

Install and run programs/drivers with admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed Motorola Device Manager?

When debugging Samsung and HTC devices I got it to work by installing that kind of software (for syncing the devices to the computer).

Answer (score 0):

Download from the following: [ABD Universal Driver](http://adbdriver.com/downloads/)

and install it. Make sure you have your device plugged in before installing and make sure you are on USB debug mode on the phone settings.