# Device is not getting detected in Eclipse

Tags: android, android-debug

I have tried all the below

#### given link but still my devices is not getting detected in Eclipse:

[My phone cannot be detected in eclipse to test run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436627/my-phone-cannot-be-detected-in-eclipse-to-test-run)

[Device not detected in Eclipse when connected with USB cable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063147/device-not-detected-in-eclipse-when-connected-with-usb-cable)

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

Can anyone tell what should i do ? where i am missing something?

Comment: What have you tried ? Do you get any kind of error ? In your Adb does it shows the device ? Please do post some screenshots.

Comment: Two questions: Which device are you using ? and Have you installed the drivers for that device ?

Comment: please install driver base on deivce specific.and still your device not detected then in CMD ->adb kill-server ->adb devices

Comment: Have you installed drivers ? Please install it and then End task the process named, `adb.exe` and restart the eclipse. See if this works..

Comment: I am trying to install the driver by using this article http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

Comment: As soon as you turn on USB debugging on device, your Operating System automatically starts for scanning drivers.

Comment: @dipali in my usb_driver directory two folders are there which one is correct? amd64 and i386

Comment: @shree202 please check my above comment

Comment: there are two usb directory folder
1)intrtnal memory
2)external memory(sd card)
please check am i right or not?

Comment: which device you are using?

Comment: inside usd_driver only two directories are there amd64 and i386

Comment: @dipali samsung quattro

Comment: @rup35h, install samsung kies from this link, http://www.samsung.com/in/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/JSP.

Comment: please install this http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/SW/201212/20121217102504170/Samsung_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones_v1.5.14.0.exe

Comment: @dipali installation done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please install this driver - 
[Samsung_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones_v1.5.14.0.exe](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/SW/201212/20121217102504170/Samsung_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones_v1.5.14.0.exe)

After installing this driver your device will be detected.

If it's not then in CMD:

```
->adb kill-server
->adb start-server
->adb devices
```

Comment: please cheeck it out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835693/unable-to-get-login-in-android-app

Comment: i am facing same issue with the micromax canvas. what should i do please help me out. @dipali

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate the usb debugging on your phone.